У меня в плагине ACF создана группа полей как вывести поле группа?
Создал группу полей в плагине ACF создал поле с типом поле группа, как ее правильно вывести в шаблоне страницы?

Вывожу их так, но у меня просто не выводится весь блок с этой версткой.
     <?php
// Получаем значение поля "cifr" из группы полей
$cifr = get_field('cifr');

// Проверяем, что значение поля "cifr" не пусто
if ($cifr) :
    $client = $cifr['client'];
    $workout = $cifr['workout'];
    $teams = $cifr['teams'];
    $projectworks = $cifr['projectworks'];
?>
<section id="counter" class="section-padding">
  <div class="overlay dark-overlay"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="counter-stat">
          <i class="icofont icofont-heart"></i>
          <span class="counter"><?php echo esc_html($client); ?></span>
          <h5>счастливых клиентов</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="counter-stat">
          <i class="icofont icofont-rocket"></i>
          <span class="counter"><?php echo esc_html($workout); ?></span></span>
          <h5>выполненных проектов</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="counter-stat">
          <i class="icofont icofont-hand-power"></i>
          <span class="counter"><?php echo esc_html($teams); ?></span></span>
          <h5>людей в команде</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="counter-stat">
          <i class="icofont icofont-shield-alt"></i>
          <span class="counter"><?php echo esc_html($projectworks); ?></span></span>
          <h5>Проектов в работе</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<?php
endif;
?>


В любой непонятной ситуации, обращайтесь к документации: ACF Group Template Usage

Проверяй настройку полей ACF в пункте - условия. На каких типах страниц - "правила местонахождения", раньше называлось - "местоположение". Вероятнее всего условие задано не верно или не соответствует текущему, где ты пробуешь запросить данные. get_field() читает текущие данные (если условия в настройке совпали), у него есть второй параметр, который иногда важен. Например, ты не прочитаешь данные записанные в условии (для всех страниц), если находишься в рубрике или записи, без указания конкретных данных get_field( "field_6066aq5b9cc4f", $product_id ).

Вероятно вы ранее работали с carbon fields :-)
Вот код который будет работать для ACF:


<section id="counter" class="section-padding">
  <div class="overlay dark-overlay"></div>
  <div class="container">

    <?php 
      // Получаем значение поля "cifr" из группы полей
      $cifr = get_field('cifr');
      
      // Проверяем, что значение поля "cifr" не пусто и выводим
      if( $cifr ) : 
      foreach( $cifr as $cifr_item ) :
      $client = $cifr_item['client'];
      $workout = $cifr_item['workout'];
      $teams = $cifr_item['teams'];
      $projectworks = $cifr_item['projectworks'];
    ?>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="counter-stat">
          <i class="icofont icofont-heart"></i>
          <span class="counter"><?php echo esc_html($client); ?></span>
          <h5>счастливых клиентов</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="counter-stat">
          <i class="icofont icofont-rocket"></i>
          <span class="counter"><?php echo esc_html($workout); ?></span></span>
          <h5>выполненных проектов</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="counter-stat">
          <i class="icofont icofont-hand-power"></i>
          <span class="counter"><?php echo esc_html($teams); ?></span></span>
          <h5>людей в команде</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="counter-stat">
          <i class="icofont icofont-shield-alt"></i>
          <span class="counter"><?php echo esc_html($projectworks); ?></span></span>
          <h5>Проектов в работе</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; wp_reset_query(); endif; ?>

  </div>
</section>



